# How to execute a subshell directly

Tags: bash, shell, exec, subshell

I have this:

```
timeout 25 bash -c '
  for i in {1..9}; do
      if read line < "$my_fifo"; then
          if test "$line" != "0"; then
                   exit 0;
           fi
      fi
  done
'
```

I don't really like that bash can't do this:

```
timeout 25 (...)
```

I don't understand why () is not considered a program by itself. Just an anonymous program... anyway..

my goals is to achieve the above but without the need to use `bash -c 'xyz'` since I won't get syntax highlighting in the quotes etc.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: `bash can't do this` I don't think it has anything to do with bash or whatever shell you use. Rather it's because the program (`timeout`), which is not a shell, expects/executes another program. A program here refers to an executable, and `(...)` is a part of the shell script itself. Bash can't make it an executable for `timeout` to "chainload" it.

Comment: Note that bash's `read` builtin supports a `-t` option as well.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround in Bash may be to define a function, export it, finally use `timeout 25 bash -c` to run the function. This is even less "directly", but at least syntax highlighting should work.

Frankly, since `timeout` is a separate program, I think there is no way to execute "directly". `timeout 25 (...)` would be possible if Bash implemented its own `timeout` and made it a keyword ([like `time`](https://superuser.com/a/1505454/432690); `time (...)` works).

Note in the below example we put `$my_fifo` in the environment of `timeout`. Your original code also requires `$my_fifo` in the environment.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
my_func() {
  for i in {1..9}; do
      if read line < "$my_fifo"; then
          if test "$line" != "0"; then
                   exit 0;
           fi
      fi
  done
}
export -f my_func
my_fifo=./fifo timeout 25 bash -c my_func
```

Comment: Note that if you add `set -o allexport` at the start of the script, all variables and functions defined from then on are exported to the environment so would be available to the separate `bash` invocation.